# EnableConfigServer is not working for native location in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am trying to configure a configuration server for all the properties in our application using @EnableConfigServer in spring boot. Please see the code below :

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cdk.config</groupId>
    <artifactId>configserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>configserver</name>
    <description>Contains all the configurations/properties required by all the services</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=config-server
server.port=9090
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file://Users/Sankest/StarterProjects/MicroServices/AllConfigurations/
spring.profiles.active=native
```

Copied all the property files to : /Users/Sankest/StarterProjects/MicroServices/AllConfigurations/

But when I try to access url at http://localhost:9090/config-server/default I am not seeing any property files and getting the following response:

```
{"name":"config-server","profiles":["default"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[]}
```

Comment: which OS are you running the app on?

Comment: Can you try with `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:/Users/Sankest/StarterProjects/MicroServices/AllConfigurations`? I guess the extra `/` is the issue.

Comment: I'm using mac and tried by removing extra / . but that didn't work

Comment: Have you tried exactly `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:/Users/Sankest/StarterProjects/MicroServices/AllConfigurations`? Just one slash after `file:`. The same is working fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct value should be `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:///Users/Sankest/StarterProjects/MicroServices/AllConfigurations/` with 3 front slashes after `file:`. One way to verify whether path is correct or not, even without running the application, is to paste the path in browser and check whether it shows all the files.
2. For default profile make sure either file name is `application.yml` or `application.properties`.
3. For other profiles e.g. `dev`, file name should be `application-dev.yml` or `application-dev.properties` (if all are in the same folder), then http://localhost:9090/config-server/dev would show both `dev` and `default` profile entries.

Answer (score 3):

Add dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so you are accessing the correct endpoint.

For example :

If you are having three files in your `AllConfigurations` folder.

The file can be yml or properties.

1. application-dev.yml
2. application-test.yml
3. application-prod.yml

The name in the left side of the `-` is application name and name in right side is profile.

So the endpoint for application-dev.yml will be

[http://localhost:9090/application/dev](http://%C2%A0http://localhost:9090/application/dev)

From the client to access the specific profile file in the config-server you need to set the active profile.

If you client application name is test
`spring.profile.active=dev`

Then it will return `test-dev` file to your client from config server.